# GULP 4 создает лишние папки

Tags: gulp, less

Переехал с 3 версии GULP с которой проблем вообще не было на 4. 
Вроде все хорошо. !НО при явном указании папки куда нужно пихать файлы, он начал создавать еще одну.

к примеру *app/less/style.less* Должна лететь в папку *dist/css/style.css*
а летит в *dist/css/**less**/style.css*

и возникает вопрос Как из конечного пути убрать папку less ?

```
gulp.task('less', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(gp.less())
        .pipe(gp.autoprefixer('last 5 versions'))
        .on("error", gp.notify.onError({
            message: "Error: <%= error.message %>",
            title: "style"
        }))
        .pipe(gp.concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gp.csso())
        .pipe(gp.rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
});
```

Comment: добавьте код таски для сброки LESS

Comment: Да уже решил проблемы. нужно было поставить .pipe(concat('style.css')).

Comment: напишите тогда это как ответ и отметьте